# How to define a server name in tornado

Tags: tornado, server-name

I'm just starting to use torando.
I can run the standard "hello world" example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, world")
application = tornado.web.Application([
     (r"/", MainHandler),
])
if __name__ == "__main__":
      application.listen(8888)
      tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The server will be used only in an local network.

I can write in browser http//:192.168.0.20:8888 and get the "Hello world" page.

How can I create a server name (for example  'myHomeServer')
and connect from browser using it:  http://myHomeServer  ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only to access it **from the same machine**:

- in `/etc/hosts`, put:

  192.168.0.20    myhomeserver

If you need to access it from **multiple machines**, 2 solutions:

- put the same line in every machine's /etc/hosts
- create an A record in a dns server in your local network

  **more info [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/install-dns-server/) if you have a linux server in your network.**

In all these scenarios, you'll still have to add the port after the servername in your browser.

Comment: Hi Apero, i need to connect from different devices (smartphone, ipad, pcs) with different OS. So I need to go for the second chioce,so the question is how to create a A record now...